# WPF passing several parameters including object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, parameters

I have simple button which do specific action like edit element. And I would like to pass a few parameters including object specifically SelectedMatch from datagrid and SelectedDate from callendar. Now i have something like this :

```
<DatePicker x:Name="dpEditDateMatch" SelectedDateFormat="Long" SelectedDate="{Binding MyDateTimeProperty2, Mode=TwoWay}" ></DatePicker>
                    <Button Content="Edit match" Command="{Binding EditMatchCommand}">
                        <Button.CommandParameter>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                                <Binding >??</Binding>
                                <Binding Path="SelectedDate" ElementName="dpEditDateMatch"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Button.CommandParameter>
                    </Button>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding match}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMatch}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

In .cs file i have definition of SelectedMatch like this:

```
object _SelectedMatch;
    public object SelectedMatch
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedMatch;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedMatch != value)
            {
                _SelectedMatch = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedMatch");
            }
        }
    }
```

How can i do that ? I mean, handle this from xaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just faced the problem you said yesterday.
And I solved it now.
Here is the XAML：

```
<Page.Resources>
            <local:MultiIcommandParameterConverter x:Key="MultiIcommandParameterConverter"></local:MultiIcommandParameterConverter>
    </Page.Resources>
 <ItemsControl>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Command="{Binding ButtonClick}">
                                        <Button.CommandParameter>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiIcommandParameterConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="DetailIndex"/>
                                                <Binding Path="DetailContent"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Button.CommandParameter>                                       
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
```

And here is code behind of INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
 public class DetailButtonClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
            {
                public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
                private void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
                {
                    if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                    }
                }           
                string _DetailContent;
                public string DetailContent
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return _DetailContent;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        _DetailContent = value;                    
                        NotifyPropertyChange("DetailContent");
                    }
                }
                string _DetailIndex;
                public string DetailIndex
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return _DetailIndex;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        _DetailIndex = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChange("DetailIndex");
                    }
                }           
                CommandClass _ButtonClick;
                public override CommandClass ButtonClick
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return _ButtonClick;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        _ButtonClick = value;
                        NotifyPropertyChange("ButtonClick");
                    }
                }
 public class CommandClass : ICommand
        {            
            public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return true;
            }
            public delegate void DelegateClickVoid(string index,string content);
            public DelegateClickVoid ClickVoid = null;            
            public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                string[] parameterArray = parameter.ToString().Split(",".ToArray());
                ClickVoid?.Invoke(parameterArray[0], parameterArray[1]);
            }

        }
            }
```

And here is code behind about IMultiValueConverter,the most important things:

```
public class MultiIcommandParameterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{        
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0] + "," + values[1];
    }

    object[] IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Totally,convert all the parameters into one parameter by using ',' to split it.While the button clicked,split the parameter by ',' into parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the data in your `ViewModel` i.e. `MyDateTimeProperty2` which is for your date and `SelectedMatch` for the match. In your MultiBinding you should pass this:

```
<Button Content="Edit match" Command="{Binding EditMatchCommand}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
            <Binding Path="MyDateTimeProperty2" />
            <Binding Path="SelectedMatch" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
```

Because Button already has the same `DataContext` as the `DatePicker` and `DataGrid` you don't even need that `x:Name="dpEditDateMatch"` on the `DatePicker` to get the data.